# Masking an image cross browser ( IE9 >)

Tags: svg, png, mask

I'm having a problem with image masking, I just can't find the right solution.

[image: Example of what i want to accomplish]

I tried several techniques but none of them are the right solution for me:

1. I've tried the mask-image: url(mask.svg) proportie but it has no fallback for IE (10 & 9)
2. I've also tried custom css3 shapes with border-radius but this won't mask the image properly.

Just using a SVG (or PNG polyfill) with a transparent shape in the middle (and place it on top of the image) will not work because i work with several textures.

Is there a way to make this work across all major browsers (IE9 and up )?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could do the whole thing as an svg perhaps? Masks inside svg should work.

Comment: An example: http://dev.w3.org/SVG/profiles/1.1F2/test/svg/masking-path-11-b.svg